# "PHP Notice: Constant DATE_RFC7231 already defined in /ext/vhosts/public/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 258"

Tags: 7, debugging

After moving my Drupal site to a new host, I got the following error in the error logs.

> [error] 8707#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Constant DATE_RFC7231 already defined in /ext/vhosts/public/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 258

How can I fix it?

My site currently says "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later"

My setup is as follows:

- Debian 8
- PHP 7.0.21
- MySQL 5.6
- Drupal 7.54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you *certain* you're running PHP 5 and not a version of PHP 7? I've only ever seen that error when running PHP 7, and it was due to [DATE_RFC7231 already defined in PHP 7.0.19 and 7.1.5](https://www.drupal.org/node/2877243).

Either way, the patches in that issue were [committed and released with 7.55](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.55), so it might be worth trying a core update before anything else.

Comment: I've just tried to update site to Drupl 7.55. I ran draush cc all, and refreshe the site, stil the same error.

Comment: I was also getting this with PHP 7 on a VM on Drupal 7. Downgraded to PHP 5, it went away. This was just this week, too.

Comment: @Chapabu, actually Drupal 7.55 did fix the error for me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I solved following this tutorial:
https://webocreation.com/blog/notice-constant-date_rfc7231-already-defined-in-includes-bootstrap-inc-on-line-258/

Open **/includes/bootstrap.inc**
Go to line number 258
Comment out the following line:

```
//define(‘DATE_RFC7231’, ‘D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T’);
```

Then add following line:

```
if (!defined(‘DATE_RFC7231’)) {
define(‘DATE_RFC7231’, ‘D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T’);
}
```

Comment: There is not need to edit a Drupal core file: It's enough to update to any Drupal 7 version that is higher than 7.54.